# Is there a configuration file for node js

Tags: node.js

I have a problem with node and SSL. solution is using `--use-openssl-ca` option when running node. but I should always run my app with that option.

Is there a configuration file for node.js which I set that option in it?

Comment: Why not just add it as a script in your `package.json`? `node index.js --use-openssl-ca`

Comment: because this problem exists in some project. really node js has not configuration file?

Comment: just add it to `package.json` or create a `bash/cmd` or whatever holding the args when calling it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering your question. yes you can attach configuration file for nodejs but there is no global config file.

```
NODE_OPTIONS='--require "./my path/file.js"'
```

but this will not make the command line shorter.

- if you are willing to add it for one specific project.

  then use `package.json` add a starter script there.
- if you want it to be in the current bash. do this (Linux) :

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--use-openssl-ca
```

in windows `set NODE_OPTIONS=--use-openssl-ca`

- if you want default in every bash.

```
echo 'export NODE_OPTIONS=--use-openssl-ca' >> ~/.bashrc
```